# What does the generate authorization process do and what is a Profile?

Tags: authorization, abap, sap-basis

While trying to understand the Authorization concept in SAP, I came across the stage where an Authorization is 'generated' resulting in a profile number.

Now I've the following questions:

Q1. What is the meaning of 'generating' an authorization. What new does the button actually do because we already have allocated an authorization object to a class. I think this only should serve the purpose of allocating this authorization to a user?

Q2. What is a profile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Profiles" are the technical stuff that the kernel reads to actually evaluate the permissions. In The Good (?) Old Days [TM], there were only profiles, maintained manually. Roles / Activity groups were built on top of this later on, adding functionality and more settings. They consequently generate profiles from the settings assembled there. This allowed for a gradual transition from manual profiles to generated profiles / roles without throwing away the kernel and user code that was known to work. You can still see this in the technical names: PRGN = profile generator...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Can we say that a profile is a collection of various authorizations which can be reused for several users?

Comment: Yes, you could say that. See also http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/52/671595439b11d1896f0000e8322d00/frameset.htm.